# Configuring touchscreen

Tags: 10.10, touchscreen

I'm trying to calibrate touchscreen on Ubuntu 10.10. My problem is that touchscreen is working, but calibration is horribly off - I'm able to navigate only a small portion of upper-left corner (while I'm pressing all over the screen). And my xorg.conf file does not even have an entry for this device.

What can you recommend me to do to configure it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Found the solution](http://setupguides.blogspot.com/2010/10/calibrating-touchscreen-in-ubuntu-1010.html)

I was able to successfully calibrate my screen using the following method:

Open a terminal and type the following:

```
xinput list
```

You should see something like this:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                     id=2 [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer               id=4 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ IDEACOM  IDC 6680                        id=8 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ IDEACOM  IDC 6680                        id=9 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad               id=13 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                    id=3 [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard              id=5 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                             id=6 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                             id=7 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB 2.0 Camera                           id=10 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus EeePC extra buttons                 id=11 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard             id=12 [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Note where it has the first "IDEACOM  IDC 6680", that's your touchscreen.  There should be an id in the second column ie. "id=8"

pass the id into the next command(I'm using 8 as the example)

```
xinput set-int-prop 8 "Evdev Axis Calibration" 32 300 7900 400 7800
```

That should have set your screen calibration, the last 4 values are the actual calibration numbers.  You may need to tweak these numbers for your monitor, so just fiddle with the values and rerun the command  until you are happy with the calibration.

At the moment you will lose your calibration when you reboot so to make it permanent do the following:

```
sudo gedit /etc/X11/Xsession.d/98x11-common_touchscreen
```

Paste you calibration command from the step above into the file and save.

Comment: Post the solution and link to the source :).

Comment: @Uri Herrera - done :)